# How to make this layout more responsive in CSS?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

Ideally I would like to have divs aligned in a more intuitive way, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stefek99/jZB2q/

[image]

I'm thinking about "get computed style" to compute heights and then change order of columns but I think it's overkill. Is there any simple strategy to make this CSS layout more aligned?

Thanks

Comment: It's doable, but then you're running face-first into the [Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem) if there's many of these blocks.

Comment: 1. You can use fixed heights in the divs and use overflow: auto
2. You can use containers for left and right column
3. use tables

Comment: @csotelo Did you mean CSS `display: table-*` ? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inline-block` to have them pack in rows of equal height.

You can give even elements `float:left` and odd ones `float:right` for less terrible packing.